# Silverlight3.0 + WCF Service hosting issues: Communication Exception

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0

I am working with silverlight3 with WCF service for a while.. I have developed and hosted my application into client mechine. It was working good. Then i need to do some modifications in my application, so I have added new functions in to my .svc file(i.e in to the wcf service). I have updated the servicereference successfully. When i re published and access it, it throws the error in a particulare method which i newly added.. But the other functions and data retreival are working good.. The newly added functions of the wcf services throws the communication error.

This is the function which i used to bind the combobox by the data retrieved from the wcf service..

### Actual Error:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object sendState)

at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(Object sendState)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)

at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)

at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)

at foundproject.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.Service1ClientChannel.EndUsergetBasedWorkgroup(IAsyncResult result)

at foundproject.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.ServiceReference1_IService1_EndUsergetBasedWorkgroup(IAsyncResult result)

at foundproject.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.OnEndUsergetBasedWorkgroup(IAsyncResult result)

at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()

at foundproject.ServiceReference1.UsergetBasedWorkgroupCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()

at foundproject.UserMaster.BindUsers(Object sender, UsergetBasedWorkgroupCompletedEventArgs e)

Please Please help me to solve it out..

It will be a great help for me..

Thanks
Lakshmi.A

Answer (score 0):

All methods in webservice are implemented using Interfaces, if you have added your function in Class file make sure its implemented by its interface-template/interface-method signature.

You have not changed the namespace of the newly added method.

the access modifier is public.

Try running your webservice file "svc" from IIS Management Console using Browse by Right clicking on "svc" file. it must show a default web service UI that we normally expect.

Debug your web service, and see if it hits the break point over your newly added method.

*I'm sure by following these simple steps you will solve your problem.*